# Why does libappstream3 break apt update on Ubuntu 16.04 (Dell Precision 7520)

Tags: 16.04, apt, dell

Why does libappstream3 break `apt update` on Ubuntu 16.04 (Dell Precision 7520)?

Even if it's is already solved, I want to inform Dell and Ubuntu users about this problem.

I've got a Dell Precision 7520.

The laptop is cool and robust, but it turns out that the Ubuntu 16.04 LTS version **provided by Dell** has a bug during `apt update`.

**Steps to reproduce:**

1. Start the computer for the 1st time,
2. See that you have a modified Ubuntu 16.04 LTS provided by Dell,
3. Finish the post installation (select timezone, create a user, ...),
4. Open a terminal
5. Run `sudo apt update`
6. The command fails because of libappstream3

   [image: error in appstreamcli: double free or corruption...]

Comment: Please remove that answer and post it as such to your question, welcome to askubuntu

Comment: This would happen to anyone doing an install using the 16.04 or 16.04.1 image if they ran sudo apt update (or sudo apt-get update). Not fatal,it'll go away once you get fully updated.(which would happen for many in the background from unattended-updates}. So not specific to Dell, they obviously are shipping the equivilant of 16.04 or 16.04.1 image

Answer (score 0):

Try the command `sudo apt-get install libappstream3`. It will fix whatever problem is there with the package.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend to [edit] this answer to expand it with specific details about how to do this. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on Ask Ubuntu.)